# How to classify a text in a category using a decision Tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, text-classification

From 2 RSS feeds, I have imported some text data, and then created 2 Document Term Matrixes (DTM's). I have been working on various stats on this DTM like most frequent terms etc, but now I want to use these two DTM's, and with 70% percent of the data train a model (Decision tree) that will be able to identify a news feed in one of the 2 categories (Education and Environment), then I will use the remaining 30% to test its performance. 
How can I do this? 
What I have done until now is:

```
# Convert Data from DTM  to Dataframe
data_fr1<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(DTM1),stringsAsFactors=False) 
data_fr2<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(DTM2),stringsAsFactors=False) 

class<-c(rep("edu",nrow(data_fr1)))
data_fr1<-cbind(data_fr1, class) # Class1 Label
class<-c(rep("env",nrow(data_fr2)))
data_fr2<-cbind(data_fr2, class) # Class2 label
```

How will I procede from there? Should I join the 2 dataframes before training the model? How will I join them and what happens to the common terms if applicable? 
How about the requirement of 70% of samples being used for the training. Should I take 70% before joining the tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one RSS for "edu" and the other for "env", yes, you should join these two data sources (and shuffle the order). Then you split the data into 70:30 (for training and testing). Because of the shuffling, we assume that the training and testing partition contain a similar distribution of labeled data.

The common terms are ok and they could still be informative (as long as the information gain for the term is not zero). For example,

```
At a certain split of the tree,
  there are 20 examples with term "biology" have the label of "edu", 
  but 180 examples with term "biology" has the label of "env", 
  and 200 examples without the term "biology".
```

If you choose to split on "biology", for the 200 examples that contain "biology",
    you would get a classification accuracy of 90% on training examples (if that split is the root). Not bad, right? (of course, you might want to keep splitting for those examples that don't have the term "biology")